# No current in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I had to find the resistance of this circuit between A and B. My teacher said that since the blank wires have zero resistance, the potential difference across the ends of the blank wire is zero(according to v = ir) and thus 1,4 are equipotent and 2,5 are equipotent and the circuit is thus simplified.The equivalent resistance comes out to be 2r/5.

MY QUESTION:If the points 1,4 and 2,5 are equi-potent how can current flow through the circuit.

MY REASONING: The potential difference across each branch of a parallel circuit is same and in this case it is 0 and hence no current can flow through the circuit.
[image]

Comment: A current flowing through an assumed 'ideal' conductor is a classical indeterminate case where \$I=\frac{V}{R}=\frac{0}{0}\$. Generally, \$\frac{0}{0}\$ can be anything between \$-\infty\$ and \$+\infty\$ depending on the context, and for your application it can be resolved by assuming \$R\$ is not zero, but 'vanishingly small' (as is \$V\$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- "If the points 1,4 and 2,5 are equi-potent how can current flow through the horizontal circuit."

No current flows "through the circuit", current flows through parts of that circuit.

- "The potential difference across each branch of a parallel circuit is same and in this case it is 0 and hence no current can flow through the circuit."

The circuit as shown is not fully parallel, only partially.

Did you try to rearrange the circuit to make the parallel parts stand out? If you do it will become much easier to understand.

Comment: By horizontal circuit i mean the middle wire, I think you understood it as the entire circuit. Right?

Comment: Correct. How did you get that the circuit that the middle wire is part of (2,3,4) has no potential difference?

Comment: I said so because 1,4 and 2,5 are equi-potent.

Comment: How did you read "1,4 and 2,5 are equi-potent"? It means that 1 and 4 are equipotent, and so are 2 and 5. It does *not* mean that 1,4,2,5 are all equipotent. 1,4 are at level A, while 2,5 are at level B.

Comment: Will any current flow between 1 and 4 and between 2 and 5 through the zero resistance wire?(V=0;R=0;I=0/0)

Comment: You shouldn't mark this as accepted if you're still arguing with it!

Comment: @pjc50 I am sorry. I had the doubt after i chose this as accepted.

Comment: Yes, current will flow through the 1,4 wire (unless A and B are at the same potential).

Answer (score 2):

Circuit diagrams are topological, which means as long as the connections stay the same, you can draw it any way you like. Allow me to redraw the circuit for you in a more clear way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwZa3U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hopefully this makes it more clear as to the current paths through the circuit, and to how the parallel resistance can be easily calculated. You can see now that current will flow through all branches of the circuit because you effectively have three parallel resistors.

Comment: A pity you did the rearranging, it is far more educational for the OP to do that himself.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple redraw (with component names) will make things clearer: -

[image]